# Sqoop is not using all the specified mappers

Tags: sqoop

I am importing data from Oracle to Hadoop using Sqoop. In Oracle table I have approximately 2 Millions records with the primary-key which is I am providing as split-by field.

My sqoop job is getting completed and I am getting correct data and job is running for 30 Min till now all good.

When I check the output file I see first file is round 1.4 GB, Second file is around 157.2 MB and last file (20th File) is around 10.4 MB whereas all the other files from 3rd to 19th are 0 bytes.

I am setting -m 20 because I want to run 20 mappers for my job.

here is the sqoop command :

sqoop import --connect "CONNECTION_STRING" --query "SELECT * FROM  WHERE  AND \$CONDITIONS" --split-by .ID --target-dir /output_data -m 20

Note : My cluster is capable enough to handle 20 mappers and database also capable to handle 20 request at a time.

Any thought?

- Dharmesh

Answer (score 5):

From http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism...

> If the actual values for the primary key are not uniformly distributed
>   across its range, then this can result in unbalanced tasks.

The `--split-by` argument can be used to choose a column with better distribution. Normally, this will vary by data type.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different --split-by field for better load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Primary Key (ID) is not uniformly distributed. Hence, your mappers are not being used appopriately. So you must use some other field for splitting that is uniformly distributed.